# Check whether time ranges exists between two given start and end times

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two fields in database named as `start_time` and `end_time` I want to get whether the user entered `value` exist between those time ranges if it exist then only my function returns `true` otherwise `false`. For that I have written this query but it does not work properly. Start time contains time in AM PM format that i have converted for eg: *7:30 AM* and *9:30 AM* for start and end time respectively. Please help to sort my issue.

```
$this->db->group_start()->where('TIME(start_time) <=',
date('H:i:s',strtotime($start_time)))->where('TIME(end_time) >=',
date('H:i:s',strtotime($end_time)))->group_end()->or_group_start()->where('TIME(start_time) <=',
date('H:i:s',strtotime($end_time)))->where('TIME(end_time) >=',
date('H:i:s',strtotime($start_time)))->group_end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the time in MySQL Query, as long as you're using same format for all entries

```
$time = "7:31 AM";
$this->db->where('start_time <=', $time);
$this->db->where('end_time >=', $time);
```

Raw Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `start_time`<='7:35 AM' AND `end_time`>='7:35 AM'
```

[image: testing in phpmyadmin]

Comment: Thanks, but i do not have to compare it with current time. There will be two input fields start time and end time which will take user input and these time range will be compared with database column for eg. start and end. In my above  query i have taken two variables for that i.e $start_time and $end_time

Comment: Can you give example of when your program should return true or false with sample data? I think you want to check if the user-given time range is in-between the time range in database, am I right?